# How to fix the dissapeared specific data retrieved from the querystring when redirected

Tags: jquery, html

I'm setting up a search on my website and the problem is, when the querystring is set and then redirects to the searchpage, the retrieved json array dissapeared and never come back.

The whole website is running on a node.js server with the Bootstrap 4 framework. What I also tried is, when the searchpage is loaded, requesting the whole database, but that slows the performance of the website.

```
function setqstring() {
    var input= $("input")[0].value; 
    $(document).ready(() => {
        window.location.replace('http://localhost/search/search.html?q='+ input)    
        $.getJSON('/action/search?q=' + GetURLParameter, function(data) {
            console.log(data);  
        });
    });

}
```

I expected that, when the querystring is set, that page redirects me to the searchpage and then  server gives me the specific json array to work with.

Comment: You need to make the `getJSON()` request from the other page after it loads

Comment: Could I also write a seperate function called `getJSON()` and then call the function onload in the body tag?

Comment: Yes....assuming the `location.replace` is to same page

Comment: According to the network tab, the browser blocked the response data. And also the console says nothing.